# Fast Write Huge File Multi Segmented C#

Tags: c#, performance, io

I develop a download manager with dynamic segmenting algorithm like IDM 
for large file becuase of multi segmented download, threads write in different space of file that maybe have 4GB distance.
because of that the writing performance decrease very much.
I don't know how to fast write this data
I tried win api WriteFile Instead of Stream.Write but I found that the problem is very much hdd head movement
I tried MemoryMappedFile with 5MB ViewStream in memory for each segment, write speed increased but not as I expected
the psudo code of using MemoryMappedFile is like this. maybe my approach of using MemoryMappedFile is incorrect

```
create MemoryMappedFile
for each  segment
create 5MB ViewStream 
write to memory stream
if data passed 5 MB or passed end of segment then close ViewStream and Create new ViewStream if not passed end of segment
```

Comment: what is the benefit? think my file is 5GB if I create 50* 100MB again head need to move across 5GB space to write in all files my problem is ver much count of seek per second in this area

Comment: Your network is faster then your disks? Get RAID of good SSD to match.

Comment: no it is not 10MB Network Speed and about 80 MB HDD Write Speed

Comment: The OS *could* make better decisions in what order to flush the MMF data in RAM to the disk.  But it is marginal, still very easy to firehose the disk drive.  It is rare to still get 80MB/sec write speeds after anti-malware is done.  And when the drive has to seek, that's always a killer.  Buy more RAM, get an SSD, this problem takes dollars to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use standard **Stream** implemenetation instead of WinAPI. Instead of writing in single file - try to write to different files, then merge them together. This way HDD will be able to do writing without 'seek' operation to concrete position in file (this is probably the reason why writing is so slow).

As to your question about moving across 5 GB - it is HDD problem in a first place, it has own buffer for solving such problems and it solves it pretty well.

When you write many small files, HDD will deside how it can rearrange it's content in buffer for better efficiency. For example, it can store chunks of data in buffer, and when the time has come to head to write some data - it will write it in one go (one circle). As you see it will also help you to multithread your writings, because you write in completely different positions in buffer.

Comment: yeah this is the reason but can you explain how multiple file solve the problem? IDM download larger file with very high write speed in my hdd

Comment: tnx I will chek it and inform you which size for small files has better performance?

Comment: In general, best file size is N*FormattingSize, so your file will be aligned in HDD and in FileSystem. Where N - is optional, you should calculate it yourself, based on your algorithm.

Comment: tnx for multiplayer I will chek with diffrent file size and will inform you

Comment: I implement what you said but thread only write in first file with  reasonable speed other threads stuck at 2 or 3 bytes per second, am I doing somthing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you just really done something wrong, I need more information how you do it.